# « Aucun résultat de trouver »

Tags: prépositions, verbes, conjugaison, infinitif, participe-passé

En tant que programmeur étranger non francophone, j'ai développé un rapport et j'ai mis la phrase *"La recherche n'a pas trouvé de résultats"*. Un de mes collègues francophones l'a changée pour *"Aucun résultat de trouver"*.

Je n'ai jamais vu ce genre de construction (*de trouver*). Est-ce qu'il y a des mots sous-entendus (par exemple, est-ce que cela veut dire "Aucun résultat [n'a été possible] de trouver") ?

Comment: *Aucun résultat de trouvé* (voir la réponse de soph-e pour la correction grammaticale et lexicale) est plutôt maladroit. Ce qui ne va pas avec la phrase que tu avais proposé c'est l'emploi du mot « trouver ».  La recherche donne, c'est le chercheur qui trouve.  « La recherche n'a pas donné de résultats. »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les attributs du sujet réel introduit par *il y a* et d'autres locutions du même genre sont parfois introduits par *de*. Grevisse indique que le tour est surtout présent à l'oral mais se trouve aussi à l'écrit et donne un *il y eut cent hommes de tués* chez Littré.  Le tour est même obligatoire dans certains cas, en particulier quand le sujet réel est un pronom comme quelqu'un, personne, rien, ceci, cela (Grevisse ne cite pas *aucun* dans la liste des pronoms qui rendent le tour obligatoire, mon instinct serait de l'ajouter; ici *aucun* n'est de toute façon pas un pronom).

*Aucun résultat de trouvé* est pour moi une abréviation de *Il n'y a aucun résultat de trouvé* qui est une phrase à mon avis grammaticalement correcte même si la version sans *de* me semble plus courante.  Pour une formulation comme *il n'y en a aucun de trouvé*, les fréquences d'utilisation me semblent inversées.

(Comme Laure, je trouve l'utilisation de *trouver* malheureuse dans ce contexte ce qui gène mon intuition qui fonctionne mieux avec *aucune place de libre*; en plus des raisons qu'elle donne, je me demande si en cherchant mieux on trouverait un résultat.)

*Aucun résultat de trouver* comporte la faute d'orthographe relativement commune d'utiliser un infinitif quand le participe passé est nécessaire.

Answer (score 7):

> Aucun résultat de trouver

est en fait une faute. Pour en être sûr, tu peux remplacer *trouver* par un autre verbe (qui ne finit pas en -er !), et puis regarde si la phrase a encore du sens.

« Aucun résultat de vendre » ne marche pas autant que « Aucun résultat de vendu ».

Un phrase plus complète ressemblerait à

> Aucun résultat n'a été trouvé (pour cette recherche).

C'est une erreur très courante en français. Pour plus d'information, lit de la documentation sur l'utilisation du [participe passé](http://www.tolearnfrench.com/exercises/exercise-french-2/exercise-french-59168.php) vs [l'infinitif](http://www.lecturel.com/ecrire/participe-passe-ou-infinitif.htm), ou sur les [homonymes](http://stdenis.weebly.com/uploads/6/3/4/0/6340863/les_homonymes_er__ez._ai.pdf).

Pour ton message d'erreur spécifiquement, il y a [ici](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/aucun+r%C3%A9sultat+trouv%C3%A9.html) beaucoup d'exemples, avec quelques variations.

Comment: étrangement, je ne trouve pas d'autres questions qui ont étés posées sur la terminaison 'er, é ou ez' dans l'historique de french.stackexchange. Si quelqu'un en trouve une, on pourrais l'ajouter comme question similaire (avec peut-être une meilleur réponse).

Comment: C'est l'oreille qui va dire si la  substitution d'un verbe du premier groupe par un en verbe en -oir ou -ir ou -re fonctionne ou pas.  Avec des non francophones ça ne fonctionne que s'ils ont déjà atteint un excellent niveau de français et un non francophone ne peut aborder la question que par le raisonnement grammatical.

Comment: @Laure Effectivement, d'où les hyperliens sur l'utilisation du participe passé vs l'infinitif. Est-ce que je devrais mettre l'emphase sur ceux-ci au lieu de sur la technique de substitution?

Comment: Les deux sont utiles je crois, j'ai mis le commentaire surtout pour rassurer les non francophones qui ne comprendraient pas ce dont tu parles. Un francophone qui a fait dans son enfance cet exercice scolaire très français que sont les dictées devraient se rappeler le « truc » tout de suite en lisant ta réponse. Et même quand on se le rappelle ça n'empêche pas des tas de français de faire l'étourderie !

Comment: Après le commentaire de @Laure, j'ai mieux compris ce que vous voulez dire. Dans le fond, mon collègue aurait dû écrire "de trouvé" plutôt que "de trouver". Et même s'il avait fait ça, ça serait encore incorrect.
Comme lusophone, je n'ai pas de difficulté à savoir quand utiliser un verbe ou un participe passé. Le plus difficile c'est de s'habituer aux erreurs des francophones, parce qu'on n'est jamais sûr s'il s'agit d'un erreur ou si c'est quelque chose qu'on n'a pas encore appris.
Merci à tous.